# Set SharedObject maximum size

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, shared-objects

Is there a way to set a (large) maximum size for SharedObject on my domain so that I can ask the user to allocate a size greater than 100k one time and not need to ask again, even if data is added?

Comment: if you can't do it 100k, your probably doin' it wrong!

Comment: what if it's audio or image data and you don't want to store it on the server =)

Answer (score 3):

If you call `SharedObject.flush(minDiskSpace:int = 0):String` without any amount value, each time you call it for append data, and if the limit is reach, a box will be opened to request the user for change the limit to match to the exact size of data (previous + appended).

So if you always add data (need more space), each time the box will be opened because the data (and the limit) always be greater than the previous one.

So set `minDiskSpace` to the value of 500k (for example) if you append 49k each time, the user will be ask for the 3th and 11th of times data is appended (only if user allow it, an error is throw for permanent disallowed storage)

See [flash.net.SharedObject.flush()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush%28%29) documentation:

> For example, if you expect a shared
>   object to grow to a maximum size of
>   500 bytes, even though it might start
>   out much smaller, pass 500 for
>   minDiskSpace. If Flash asks the user
>   to allot disk space for the shared
>   object, it asks for 500 bytes. After
>   the user allots the requested amount
>   of space, Flash won't have to ask for
>   more space on future attempts to flush
>   the object (as long as its size
>   doesn't exceed 500 bytes).
>
> After the user responds to the dialog
>   box, this method is called again. A
>   netStatus event is dispatched with a
>   code property of
>   SharedObject.Flush.Success or
>   SharedObject.Flush.Failed.